# Do compilers optimize memset in destructor?

Tags: c++, optimization

Given a struct like:

```
struct CryptoKey {
    std::vector<unsigned char> key;
    ~CryptoKey() { memset(key.data(),0,key.size()); }
};
```

The compiler is *entitled* to eliminate the call to `memset` because this will save time, and no program with defined behaviour can tell the difference.  (Given that the variable `key` will cease to exist once the destructor returns.)

Nevertheless, code like this is useful in cryptographic applications, because the less time that a secret is stored in memory, the less chance an attacker has to extract it.  (The `memset` does not provide security, but it does provide "defence in depth".)

My question is, which real compilers actually *do* eliminate such `memset` calls (obviously, with optimization turned on)?

Comment: yes they do (gcc, clang and recent MSVC at least), if you enable optimisations.

Comment: Search for `explicit_bzero`.

Comment: @RichardHodges: That's an answer (and covers all the compilers I am interested in - with the wrong answer).

Comment: @MartinBonner did you edit the question, or did I read it wrongly? (I suspect the latter).

Comment: @RichardHodges  I haven't edited the question.  I want the memset to stay in; I read your comment as saying the memset gets removed.  Searching for Marc Glisse's `explicit_bzero` suggests this is a real problem in libressl ports.

Comment: @RichardHodges: When I say "wrong answer", I meant "not the answer I was hoping to get" as opposed to "factually incorrect answer".

Comment: @RichardHodges According to my tests, `clang` and `gcc` with `-O3` will only optimize out `memset` on regular arrays but not with `std::vector`.

Comment: @ShmuelH. that makes sense actually. memset is already optimally efficient for an array of indeterminate length. I note that `std::fill(beg, end, 0)` gets reduced to memset on a `vector<int>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem for optimizers here is that your memset isn't writing to a member at all. Yes, `key` will cease to exist, but not so `key.data`. That memory will be returned to `std::allocator`. And `std::allocator` will very likely read adjacent memory to determine the memory block from which `key.data` came. Typical implementations store such data in the header of allocated blocks, i.e. at negative offsets. It's not unlikely that the header will be updated to reflect the block is free, or to coalesce the free block with other free blocks.

This may even be inlined, so the optimizer sees one function doing a `memset` and then the header access. It would be unreasonable to expect that the optimizer can figure out the `memset` is harmless. For all it knows, the allocator may be keeping a pool of zeroed blocks.

Comment: Right.  So a sufficiently advanced optimizer *can* remove the code (although it must be careful to not do this for user provided allocators), but in practise nobody is going to spend time trying to optimize this case (but it could happen to fall out of some other useful optimization).

Comment: *"It would be unreasonable for the optimizer to figure out the memset is harmless."* Did you mean to have a **not** in there?

Comment: @CodyGray: I missed more than that; rewritten.

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps it is better to say that a good compiler would attempt to eliminate the memset call and a developer should not rely on differences of compiler implementation to avoid this optimisation.  These compilers typically have secure alternatives that will not be optimised.

**Secure version of memset**

C11 introduces memset_s which one of the characteristics is that is will not be optimised out.

> Unlike memset, any call to the memset_s function shall be evaluated strictly according to the rules of the abstract machine as described in (5.1.2.3). That is, any call to the memset_s function shall assume that the memory indicated by s and n may be accessible in the future and thus must contain the values indicated by c.

**Windows specific**

On windows there are other choices.  `SecureZeroMemory` or using a `#pragma optimize` pragma to turn off optimisation.

**Common sub-expression optimisations**

There is a broader issue with cryptographic safety: compilers are within their rights to copy buffers for optimisation reasons.  Zeroing may not remove all copies, the compiler may have applied optimisations that copy the heap to the stack to eliminate common sub-expressions. So besides avoiding optimising out the zeroing, care should be taken that the compiler isn't inserting additional copies.

Comment: Unfortunately, according to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memset) `memset_s` is only available if `__STDC_LIB_EXT1__` is defined (which in practise means  "Windows only"), and is not part of C++ at all.  But +1 for "a developer should not rely ..."

Comment: In practice this is to capture those earlier compilers, being native on OS X and Linux.  Windows having alternatives. That is C++ is built on libc and that libc ought to be C11 compatible.

Comment: I don't understand your last comment.  A C implementation can be fully C11 compliant without including `memset_s` (it is optional).  glibc does not include `memset_s`.

Comment: Don't use `#pragma optimize`, that's too big of a hammer with other suboptimal consequences. `SecureZeroMemory` is fine, the compiler knows not to optimize it out.