# Is there any way to zero out all memory upon program exit in C++ for sensitive data applications?

Tags: c++, security, gcc, clang

Just calling free() on allocated memory doesn't clear the data from RAM and neither do stack pop operations and can be recovered by RAM dump AFAIK. I thought of just setting sensitive data to zero in destructors but the compiler likes to optimise away unused values. For security sensitive applications, is there any way to prevent that apart from disabling optimisations? Or even better, some compiler flag or system call that automatically zeroes used memory upon program exit?

Comment: Related: [Do compilers optimize memset in destructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41502725/11082165). See also the notes on [`std::memset`'s cppreference page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memset) for ways to ensure that memory fills aren't optimized away.

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42771298/explicitly-removing-sensitive-data-from-memory, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10683941/clearing-memory-securely-and-reallocations, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5698002/how-does-one-securely-clear-stdstring

Comment: You probably want to zero on free, not just on exit. Data can persist for several minutes after physical removal of power, and physical removal of power will stop any `atexit` routines from running. In short, zero sensitive data as soon as you can, don't wait for exit.

Comment: See @Brian comments for suggestions.

Comment: @Brian, looks like a good answer to me.

Comment: Also note that you have to `mlock` or else you risk the sensitive data being written to swap, which is even more persistent.